# Javascript to html replace tags not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on this to replace every code that is shared on post in my website but is not working for me.
I need everything that appear inside `<pre><code></code></pre>`to replay all the tags and give it a color using css. please if there is any simple way to do this can someone just help me with that? i will appreciate sample code in jsfiled

here is sample of code that i have been trying to use

```
function Rep(text){
  text = text.replace(/ /g,"&nbsp;");

  text = text.replace(/<([^\>]+?)>/g, function(match, contents){
      return "<span class='TagColor'>&lt;"+contents+"&gt;</span>";
  }  
  );

  text = text.replace(/\"([^\"]+?)\"/g, function(match, contents){
      return '<span class="StringColor">&quot;'+contents+'&quot;</span>';
    }  
  );
  text = text.replace(/\(([^\)]+?)\)/g, function(match, contents){
      return '<span class="OptionsColor">('+contents+')</span>';
    }  
  );
  text = text.replace(/\n/g, function(match, contents){
      return '<br />';
  }  
  );
  text = text.replace(/\{/g, function(match, contents){
      return '<span class="BracketsColor">&#123;</span>';
  }
  );
  text = text.replace(/\}/g, function(match, contents){
      return '<span class="BracketsColor">&#125;</span>';
  }
  );
  text = text.replace(/\/\*([^\*]+?)\*\//g, function(match, contents){
      return "<span class='CommentColor'>/*"+contents+"*/</span>";
  }  
  );
    text = text.replace(/\[\](.*?)\[\/\]/g, function(match, contents){
      return '<span class="BBColor">'+contents+'</span>';
  }
  );
  return text;

}

//HTML replace
//==================================================
$('code').each(function(){
    var text=$(this).html().replace(/</g,'&lt;');
    var text=text.replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
    $(this).html(text);
});

//google-code-prettify
//==================================================
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    prettyPrint();
});

//Still on Text format                                                                                                                

var app = angular.module('codelab',[],['$interpolateProvider',
    function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
        }]);

app.directive('ngPrism',['$interpolate', function ($interpolate) {
        "use strict";
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: '<pre id="Mpreditor" class="code code-codes language-javascript"><code ng-transclude="ng-transclude" class="language-javascript"> </code></pre>',
          replace:true,
          transclude:true
        };
    }]);
```

And here is how codes display in my website

```
    <pre id="Mpreditor" class="code code-codes language-javascript">
    <code ng-transclude="ng-transclude" class="language-javascript">    
<span>Hello</span>
You have to include the `%` signs in the `$params`, not in the query:

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE address LIKE ? OR address LIKE ?";
        $params = array("%$var1%", "%$var2%");
        $stmt = $handle-&gt;prepare($query);
        $stmt-&gt;execute($params);
        </code></pre>
```

Comment: do your `rep()` call after  your `<code>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to implement it yourself you should try using some library.

There are certain things to consider before going about it.

1. Store your actual code in `<script>` tag, any other tag will force browser to parse the content that may result in modification of the code like `HTML`
2. Don't append the code in the container as `HTML` but `textNode` for the same reason as first point

I have implemented a sample from using this https://highlightjs.org/usage/ library below.

```html
 <html>
 <head>
  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.4.0/styles/default.min.css">
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.4.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

 <script class="testCode" type="text/code" lang="sql">
 SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE address LIKE ? OR address LIKE ?
 </script>

 <script class="testCode" type="text/code" lang="html">
 <html>
   <head>
   
   </head>
   <body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
   </body>
 </html>
 </script>

 <script class="testCode" type="text/code" lang="java">
 public class Test {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
   System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
 }
 </script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="codeContainer">
 </div>

 <script>
  //create code blocks
  var codes = $("script.testCode");
  var container = $("#codeContainer");
  
  codes.each(function () {
   var code = $(this);
   var html = code.html();
   var language = code.attr("lang");
   var codeBlock = $("<pre><code class='" + language + "'></code></pre>");
   codeBlock.find("code").text(html);
   container.append(codeBlock);
  });
 </script>
 <script>
 hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
 </script>


 </body>
 </html>
```